# How to set 3 div's to fit the screen width

Tags: css, html, center

Hi all I have problem with my div's in html. I have set them correctly in chrome but when I am using firefox or IE my last div is going in the next row.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id="vis"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
<div>
```

And their css:

```
body 
{ 
 height: 100%; 
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0 ;
 border: 0 none;
}
#left
{
background-color:#EEEEEE;
height:570px;
width:73.9%;
float:left;
}
#menu
{
background-color:#D4EAE4;
color:#535353;
height:570px;
width:15.25%;
float:left;
margin:0;
}
#vis
{
background-color:#D4EAE4;
 float:left;
 width:11%;
 height:570px;
 margin:0;
}
#container
 {
 width:98%;
 padding-left:1%;
 padding-right:1%;
 }
#header
 {
 background-color:#4671D5;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 100px 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px 50px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 100px 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px 50px;
 }
```

How can I make this div's to fit to each other perfectly in other browsers too? Chrome is exactly what I need. Safari gives me gap between `vis` and `menu` of 2px and IE and Firefox is putting my last div `vis` in the new row. Header and footer are okay. I just put them so you can test it at your pc. And I want to have `%` as I want this to be usable to all resolutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change menu css to

```
#menu 
{ 
background-color:#D4EAE4; 
color:#535353; 
height:570px; 
width:15.1%;//previos 15.25% 
float:left; 
margin:0; 
}
```

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/J5fVj/2/

Comment: Does this solve your problem? You may need to test because, when I tested it, your div still wraps down. I have the solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/J5fVj/

Answer (score 3):

Solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/J5fVj/

- no more wrapping
- no more space in between divs

HTML: (with sample texts for testing)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="menu">menu</div>
    <div id="vis">vis</div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
<div>​
```

UPDATED STYLESHEET:

```
body 
{ 
 height: 100%; 
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0 ;
 border: 0 none;
}
#left
{
background-color:#EEEEEE;
height:570px;
width:73.9%;
display: inline-block;
}
#menu
{
background-color:#D4EAE4;
color:#535353;
height:570px;
width:15.25%;
display: inline-block;
margin:0;
}
#vis
{
 background-color:#D4EAE4;
 display: inline-block;
 width:11%;
 height:570px;
 margin:0;
    border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}
#container
 {
 width:98%;
 padding-left:1%;
 padding-right:1%;
 white-space: nowrap;
 font-size: 0;
 }
#header
 {
 background-color:#4671D5;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 100px 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px 50px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 100px 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px 50px;
}

#header, #left, #menu, #vis { font-size: 20px; text-align: center; }
```

​--

The **white-space: nowrap**, **font-size: 0**, **display: inline-blocks** did the trick.

Comment: Your answer is the best here :)

Answer (score 1):

The percentages of your 3 divs add up to slightly over 100% which is probably causing a problem. Try decreasing the size of the left div to 72%

Comment: then on the right side I have problem with footer and header I have a gap. Can you try to make fast html page with this code. So you can see whats's wrong please

Comment: sadly i cant as I am at work. The problem will definately be with the percentages though, you just need to tweak them all a little bit.

Comment: The wrapping will always occur when white-spaces are around separating each div. The only solution here is to declare `white-space: nowrap;` to turn off wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should also define `margin` for `div#container` (e.g. `margin: 0;`) to be the same on each browser. When it's not defined, browser use default value and it can be various on various browsers and then your precise width calculations can failed.